# How do I access my irc server over the internet if I'm using my phone for internet access for the pc

Tags: debian, internet, irc, ircd

I'm running debian on my home pc. For irc server setup, I installed `ircd-hybrid`. I happen to have 4G mobile data on my phone and am using it to access the internet using usb tethering through the pc. Now, I'm aware of the fact that tethering ip's are dynamic and they change to a new one on reconnection. But as long as I'm connected to the net, the ip does not change afaik. I am not leaning towards a domain name because it's just a temporary experiment. I guess port forwarding is involved in some way. My objectives are to run the irc server on my home pc, and connect to it from another device through a client not on a local network, but through the internet. Have you tried something like this before? Is it even possible to setup irc server this way? What are your thoughts?

Comment: Check out https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/168422/how-to-port-forward-internet-using-android-hotspot-to-pc/207342.

Comment: @FerencWágner excellent suggestion! I would give it a try for sure. Much appreciated!